# How to prove this: log n = O(n^c)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

[image]

In a data structure textbook, the author use this to prove that O(log^c(n))is effective because the complexity is very close to the constant, I don't quite understand the equation.

Comment: not quite sure what the point here is but `log n` is already in `O(n)`, remember that big-o is only an upper bound ("smaller equals"). Hence it is also in `O(n^c)` for whatever constant (assuming natural number `> 0` as stated in the image, so `n^1, n^2, n^3, ...`).

Comment: @Zabuzard thats not so clear for c < 1, c does not have to be an integer.

Comment: @Henry Hence I said _natural number_.

Comment: Do you have a link or the name of the book, i.e. the source? It might contain more information than this small snippet which will likely help people answering the question.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Does the logarithm function grow slower than any polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1663818/82433)

Comment: @harold It is, but I think that the answer that I gave here is more likely to be understood by a CS student than the answer found there.  (I've found that Calculus students mostly fall into two groups.  Those that don't remember l'Hôpital's rule, and those who misapply it.  Those who actually understand it are a small minority.)

Comment: The equation reads: For every positive value `c` then `log n` is upper bounded by the function `n^c`. This means for very large `n` it is smaller than any polynomial function. This is all it says. You can't assert much from this. Yes it's smaller than any polynomial function but still worse than infinitely many other functions so this is not an assertion that it's fast. Just that it's faster than some classes of algorithms

Comment: @apokryfos Mathematically that is so.  But in practice, `log(n)` is a constant.  For large data sets, it is a slightly larger constant.  Going from a million records to a trillion, actual performance issues come from hitting limits that force you from RAM on one machine to distributed, and not due to the growth of `log(n)`.

Comment: @Zabuzard Sorry I didn't provide the context because it's from a Chinese book, you can refer to page 5 in this slide: https://drive.google.com/file/d/157WnF9gG7tqVDVW5V3jAIQhkEgN5UAYW/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

The intuitive reason why this is is true is that `log` is the inverse of `e^x`.  Just as the exponential function grows faster than `x^k` for any `k`, its inverse must grow slower than `x^(1/k)` for any `k`.  (Draw pictures and flip the x and y axis to get this intuition.)

However intuition does not lead to a formal proof.

So first, convince yourself that `log(log(n)) = o(log(n))`.

From that, for any given `c`, there is an `N` such that for all `n > N` that `log(log(n)) < c log(n)`.  Now take `e^x` of both sides and you have found that for sufficiently large `n`, `log(n) < n^c`.  And therefore `log(n) = O(n^c)` for any given `c`.

But that is big-O.  We wanted little-o.  Well, `log(n) = O(n^(c/2)` which means that `log(n)` is actually in `o(n^c)`.  And now we're done.